# Laravel solo regresa estatus 200 en encabezados

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Recien formatie mi computadora y las apis de mi proyecto en laravel no regresan los encabezados de forma correcta.

los encabezados solo regresan estatus 200 cuando deberian regresar 400.
Alguien sabe que configuracion deberia tener ya sea apache o laravel? para que funcione correctamente?

Saludos.

```php
public function menu(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            ParametrosHttpValidador::validar($request, $this->servicio->getReglasMenu());
            $menu = $this->servicio->getmenu($request->all());
            return Respuesta::json($menu, 200);
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
dd($e);
            return Respuesta::error($e);
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: api]

Middleware Cors

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization',
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => 'X-Message'
        ];
        $response = $next($request);

        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->headers->set($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y coloca el código como texto, no como imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Solucione el problema corriendo el servidor como administrador

1. sudo su
2. Correr el servicio con el comando:

   ```
   php artisan serve** --host=miaplicacion.com
   ```

el host es opcional,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]